# nginx configuration settings on a server with two hostnames, two IP addresses and two conf files; what's going wrong?

Tags: nginx, ssl

(edit - this was solved, I needed to listen at the specific IPs.  I put in the correct solution in the .conf section below and put comments showing what I removed)

I am trying to find out what's wrong with my nginx configuration, it's been baffling me for a couple of days and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  I've had this server for a year+ with a single domain name and things have been running fine.  Now I want to start hosting a second domain on the same server and my issues start occuring when I'm trying to use the second domain name.

The setup;

- two domains (server.info, .26 & server.dev, .30), each with separate DNS records
- one dedicated server with two IP addresses (.26 & .30) assigned to the same eth1
- nginx configured as a reverse proxy for all incoming traffic

I have been using .api with a single nginx.conf with no issues.  I added another domain name and thought I would try to use a single .conf file for both domains.  I updated the SSL cert to accept both domains and here's where I noticed the first issue.  Traffic going to .dev didn't seem to be routed properly.  For example, when trying to go to server.dev root in a browser it would load the index.html file from server.info directory.  Everything on .info continued to work fine, but it seems like .dev wasn't being recognized at all.  Here is the the .conf file with two domains;

```
server {
    listen                  1.2.3.26:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             www.server.info;
    root                    /var/www/server.info/;
    index                   index.html;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.info/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.info/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.info/chain.pem;
    
    # security
    include                 nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/server.info.access.log;

    # I removed all of my /location redirects...

}


# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      1.2.3.26:80;
    server_name server.info;
    root        /var/www/server.info/;
    index       index.html;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.server.info$request_uri;
    }



}

server {
    listen      1.2.3.26:80;
    server_name www.server.info;
    root        /var/www/server.info/;
    index       index.html;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.server.info$request_uri;
    }
}






server {
    listen                  1.2.3.30:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             www.server.dev;
    root                    /var/www/server.dev/;
    index                   index.html;

    # security
    include                 nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/server.dev.access.log;


 }


# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      1.2.3.30:80;
    server_name server.dev;
    root        /var/www/server.dev/;
    index       index.html;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.server.dev$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen      1.2.3.30:80;
    server_name www.server.dev;
    root        /var/www/server.dev/;
    index       index.html;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.server.dev$request_uri;
    }
}
```

If I split into two conf files (dev.conf & api.conf), relinked directories, restarted, etc - the situation became even stranger.  At this stage .api wasn't accepting traffic at all, but ONLY .dev started working (using the correct index.html).

The only difference in .conf files when I split the two is I added the SSL certs to .dev.  nginx -t always passes.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to `listen` on the specific IP for the server, rather than listening on any interface as you are now: https://serverfault.com/questions/426084/how-to-define-two-servers-on-different-ips-in-nginx

Comment: This solved it, I knew it had to be something obvious.  :-)  Thank you so much!!